# Which tools can be used for performance testing of a mobile application

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests

I am a Tester and i want your suggestions on selecting the tool for testing the performance of the list view and page load time of the mobile application with the following parameters ie., CPU Usage,Memory usage,please suggest me for the open source tools and paid version tools both.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of android studio built-in tools along with command line tools that come packaged with Android sdk, which you can use to profile your android applications:

- GPU Profiler / Graphics API debugger
- systrace
- traceview
- dumpsys
- dmtracedump
- CPU Profiler
- Memory Profiler
- Network Profiler
- Batterystats
- ApkAnalyzer

Comment: will i be able to see the response time of the application with it?

Comment: other than android studio is there any other tool?

Comment: systrace, dumpsys, dmtracedump, batterystats are not included in Android Studio, they are standalone tools. Furthermore, You can use systrace and traceview to determine bottlenecks in your app's responsiveness.

Comment: You can also view your app's performance online in Play console under `Android vitals` which display metrics like anr rates, crash rates, startup time, slow/frozen frames etc.